# How to retrieve multiple values from temp tables and insert them into another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temp table with the following values

```
@TempTable
ID
1
2
```

for each ID in the temp table I want to execute the following:

```
insert into ItemOrganisationSources
    select ByLineID, <TempTable.ID>, SourceTypeID
    from ItemOrganisationSources
    where ItemOrganisationID in (
        select ID from @TempTable)
```

Comment: You can loop through temp table records by using Cursor.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like the final result to look like? I thought I had an answer for this, but now I'm thinking I may have misread your question.

Comment: @VijaysingGusinge you should avoid cursors unless absolutely necessary and prefer the set-based operations in sql first.

Comment: Also, is `@itemOrganisationIDsToBeDuplicated)` meant to be the same thing as @TempTable, or is that a separate table variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your code whether you have a temp table (which is prefixed by '#') or a table variable (which is prefixed by '@', like your example). Either way, though, you can reference a temp table/variable just like any other table.

Table variable:

```
insert into ItemOrganisationSources
    select i.ByLineID, t.ID, i.SourceTypeID
    from ItemOrganisationSources AS i
    inner join @TempTable AS t
      on i.ID = t.ID --Plug in the appropriate field to join on here
    where i.ItemOrganisationID in (
        select ID from @itemOrganisationIDsToBeDuplicated)
```

Temp table:

```
insert into ItemOrganisationSources
    select i.ByLineID, t.ID, i.SourceTypeID
    from ItemOrganisationSources AS i
    inner join #TempTable AS t
      on i.ID = t.ID --Plug in the appropriate field to join on here
    where i.ItemOrganisationID in (
        select ID from @itemOrganisationIDsToBeDuplicated)
```

After reading your question again, I'm not totally sure if you're trying to join your temp table to the other data, or just do the insert once for each ID in the temp table. If it's the latter, this could be a rare use for `CROSS JOIN`:

```
insert into ItemOrganisationSources
    select i.ByLineID, t.ID, i.SourceTypeID
    from ItemOrganisationSources AS i
    cross join #TempTable AS t --cross join instead of inner join
    where i.ItemOrganisationID in (
        select ID from @itemOrganisationIDsToBeDuplicated)
```

Comment: Cross join is not that rare beast :) And for cross join you have accidentally not deleted join condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
    insert into ItemOrganisationSources
    select ByLineID, TT.ID, SourceTypeID
    from ItemOrganisationSources IO JOIN
        @TempTable TT ON TT.ID = IO.ItemOrganisationID
```